# compare two relations in PigLatin

Tags: apache-pig

How do I compare tow big relations whether they contain exactly equal records or not.

Two relations can have a lot of records like 1 million rows and each row will be having 500 columns . How can I confirm whether all the records in one relation are exactly same as the records in other relation.

Comment: can you do a join on some field? is there a unique id? If so, join and compare the fields of each new record.

Comment: before joining, you might want to group date from both sets on certain fields to reduce the number of rows participating in JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
1.First load the relation in one alias with only one column say 'a',
2.Found its count(no. of rows)
3.Then load the second relation in another alias with only one column say 'b',
4.Found its count(no. of rows)
5.Join(Inner) the above two relations using columns a and b
6.then count the number of rows in the joined relation
7.compare the first relation count with join relation count or compare the second relation count with join relation count, if it is equal then both relations having same data.
```

Comment: isn't there some join missing? or how are you going to compare a and b if they are in two different relations?

Comment: There is no unique id. All I know is that all relations have same number of columns for each row and same number of rows . But I want to compare that all the contents of rows in tow relations are same.

Comment: first load the data into a relation with only one column and then group it by all then take a count for a group, do it for the second  relation also then join it by group count column.